# dependent dropdown is not working PHP

Tags: php, javascript

In this code i want to select exam and it should reflect course_code of corresponding exams and when i select exam name it is not populating another dropdown,So please any one help me.

**upload1_view.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/
    ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function()
   {
   $(".hai").change(function()
     {
    var id=$(this).val();
  var dataString = 'course_code='+ course_code;

   $.ajax
    ({
    type: "POST",
     url: "upload2_view.php",
  data: dataString,
      cache: false,
    success: function(html)
   {
  $(".hai2").html(html);
   } 
   });

  });
    });
</script></script>
</head>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
  File to import:<br />
  <input size='30' type='file' name='filename'>
  Select Exam name:<select name=hai class="hai">
  <?php
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("Error connecting to database: ".mysql_error());

        mysql_select_db("slseatapp") or die(mysql_error());

      $query="select  distinct exam_name from examcourse";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    while($nt=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<option value='".$nt['exam_name']."'>".$nt['exam_name']."</option>";
     }
    ?>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
<?php 
  mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("Error connecting to database: ".mysql_error());

  mysql_select_db("slseatapp") or die(mysql_error());

  //Upload File 
  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
  if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'])) { 




  //Import uploaded file to Database 
  $row = 1; 
  $handle = fopen($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], "r"); 
  $var = $_POST['hai'];
  $var1 = $_POST['hai2'];




  while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) { 

    //Update Database Values 

  $import="insert into student_table (id,register_number,name,course_code,subject_code,exam_name) VALUES('".mysql_real_escape_string($data[0])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($data[1])."','".mysql_real_escape_string($data[2])."','$var','$var1','$var2')"; 
  $import="replace into  student_table (id,register_number,name,course_code,subject_code,exam_name) VALUES('".mysql_real_escape_string($data[0])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($data[1])."','".mysql_real_escape_string($data[2])."','$var','$var1','$var2')";


  mysql_query($import) or die(mysql_error()); 


  } 


  }
     fclose($handle); 
  echo"<script>alert('Uploaded Successfully');</script>";

   } 
  ?>
<br />
```

**2.Upload2_view.php**

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
File to import:<br />
Course code:<select name=hai2 class="hai2">
<?php
  $query="SELECT distinct course_code FROM examcourse where exam_name =$exam_name;
       $result = mysql_query($query);
      while($nt=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
      echo "<option value='".$nt['course_code']."'>".$nt['course_code']."</option>";
         }
        ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Does the `Upload2_view.php` actually contain a `<form>` in it?!? The way I understand it, `Upload2_view.php` should merely be returning the html-code to be put into the `<select>`tag of the calling page,  i.e. `<option>` tags only.

Comment: these lines are not really good: `<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/
        ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: You need to be clear on your question. Are both php being included in the same file? the code of the first php (appart from being horrifying) seems to try to populate an element with class "hai2" with the result of the ajax query to the second php. However this "hai2" element seems to exist only on the second php.

Comment: Upload1_view.php and  Upload2_view.php  are different php file

Comment: Upload1_view.php should populate upload2_view.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Please changes the following error:**

Remove first script tag. Dont remove code between that script tag

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

</script>
```

Please find the course_code, course_code was not found
it will -

```
var dataString = 'course_code='+ id;
```

Add one span tag which you want to display the second dropdown:

```
<span class="hai2">

</span>
```

Remove the class="hai2" in second dropdown

```
Course code:<select name="hai2">
```

Upload1_view.php should be upload2_view.php

Complete code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
     {
     $(".hai").change(function()
       {
      var id=$(this).val();
      // Please find the course_code, course_code was not found
   var dataString = 'course_code='+ id;

     $.ajax
      ({
      type: "POST",
       url: "upload2_view.php",
    data: dataString,
        cache: false,
      success: function(html)
     {
   $(".hai2").html(html);
     } 
     });

   });
      });
</script>
 </head>



   <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">

    File to import:<br />

 <input size='30' type='file' name='filename'>

   Select Exam name:<select name=hai class="hai">

      <?php
   mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("Error connecting to database: ".mysql_error());

       mysql_select_db("slseatapp") or die(mysql_error());

     $query="select  distinct exam_name from examcourse";
  $result = mysql_query($query);
  while($nt=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
 echo "<option value='".$nt['exam_name']."'>".$nt['exam_name']."</option>";
    }
   ?>
  </select>
  <!--PLEASE DEFINE WHERE YOU WANT PUT YOUR SECOND DROPDOWN-->
  <span class="hai2">

  </span>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload"></form>



 <?php 

    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("Error connecting to database: ".mysql_error());

  mysql_select_db("slseatapp") or die(mysql_error());

//Upload File 
 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
 if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'])) { 




//Import uploaded file to Database 
$row = 1; 
$handle = fopen($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], "r"); 
    $var = $_POST['hai'];
  $var1 = $_POST['hai2'];




while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) { 

      //Update Database Values 

   $import="insert into student_table (id,register_number,name,course_code,subject_code,exam_name) VALUES('".mysql_real_escape_string($data[0])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($data[1])."','".mysql_real_escape_string($data[2])."','$var','$var1','$var2')"; 
   $import="replace into  student_table (id,register_number,name,course_code,subject_code,exam_name) VALUES('".mysql_real_escape_string($data[0])."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($data[1])."','".mysql_real_escape_string($data[2])."','$var','$var1','$var2')";


 mysql_query($import) or die(mysql_error()); 
} 
}
fclose($handle); 
echo"<script>alert('Uploaded Successfully');</script>";

     } 
?>
```

2.upload_view2.php

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">

  File to import:<br />


Course code:<select name="hai2">
    <?php

$query="SELECT distinct course_code FROM examcourse where exam_name =$exam_name";
  $result = mysql_query($query);
 while($nt=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
 echo "<option value='".$nt['course_code']."'>".$nt['course_code']."</option>";
    }
   ?>

  </select>
```

Comment: I tried the code but did not populate the corresponding dropdown

Comment: your Upload2_view.php should be upload2_view.php

please change it.

Comment: It is not populating after i make changes @ Chinmay Sahu

Comment: Tell me what is the variable **$exam_name** in update2_view.php page.  This variable not define

Comment: it is populating the same dropdown

Comment: yes it it populating that what you want to display from upload2_view.php page. But i was checking it using static option.

Comment: how to pass  $var = $_POST['hai2']; from upload_view2.php to upload2_view.php

Comment: Send me the db table i will do and send your email id. my id chinmay235@gmail.com . Write the details requirement what you want to do this page.